# What is it called, when a situation is described in a complicated way instead of a simple one?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, vocabulary

How do you say in English, when one describes the matter in a more complicated manner than it is?

For instance, one has two options, A and B; and either of them has to be accepted. One wants to say the same matter in either of the following two ways:

> 1. Incorrectly failing to reject A.
> 2. Incorrectly accepting A.

Both 1) and 2) are equivalent statements, but in 1) the person is speaking in a complicated way.

In other words, what a *situation/way* is called when it is being described in a complicated manner, instead of simple one.

I hope, you understand what I want to ask.

Comment: 1 and 2 aren't equivalent statements. Failing to reject something doesn't mean accepting it. It simply means you haven't obtained the means to reject it yet, and may never do so. Think of "reject" as "prove". Just because you fail to prove something false, doesn't mean it's true. It could still be indeterminate. In statistical inferences, reject and fail to reject are the only options--acceptance can't be justified by any test. Science works this way. 2 is an oversimplification, and 1 is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sentence is **verbose** and uses a **convoluted** language.

> verbose:
> Using or expressed in more words than are needed:
> much academic language is obscure and verbose
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verbose)
>
> convoluted:
> (Especially of an argument, story, or sentence) extremely
> complex and difficult to follow: the film is let down by a convoluted
> plot in which nothing really happens
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/convoluted)

Answer (score 2):

If the complicated language is deliberately intended to confuse, you might say it is **obfuscated**, **cryptic** or **obscure**.

On the other hand, if it is more of a stylistic feature, perhaps expressing something about the character of the author, you could say it is **arcane** or **ostentatious** or **overwrought**.

(As a pedantic aside, "accepting" and "failing to reject" are not identical, and there are some technical situations in which such a distinction could be important.)