# Word that describes when someone repeats the same information, rambling on and beats around the bush

Tags: single-word-requests

Having to sit through a 20 min video to get information which could be put a 5 min video.

Comment: Perhaps the person who complained that I didn't spot the exact duplicate last time would check the many results given in an in-house search for 'long-winded', 'prolix' and 'verbose'. Somehow, I doubt it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you called? I'm not online 24/7 you know. Why would you doubt it? It's not my mission to close every SWR as a duplicate only those that cannot be reopened with a "cavillo" (can't think of the word, maybe I should ask a SWR myself.) Or are you referring to another user? I hope so.

Comment: closely related:[What is it called when you use many words to describe the word you want to use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232063/what-is-it-called-when-you-use-many-words-to-describe-the-word-you-want-to-use) and [What is it called, when a situation is described in a complicated way instead of a simple one?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203628/what-is-it-called-when-a-situation-is-described-in-a-complicated-way-instead-of?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Also closely related: [What is the name of the tactic that politicians use to bury people with torrent of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160126/what-is-the-name-of-the-tactic-that-politicians-use-to-bury-people-with-torrent?noredirect=1&lq=1). Related but slightly less so: [What is a term or idiom for “blah blah blah” talk?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316399/what-is-a-term-or-idiom-for-blah-blah-blah-talk) Almost a duplicate: [Opposite of “straight talk”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96684/opposite-of-straight-talk)

Comment: Almost another duplicate but not quite:[Word to describe “when someone describes something in too much detail”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94774/word-to-describe-when-someone-describes-something-in-too-much-detail?noredirect=1&lq=1) Would be a duplicate but here the OP is asking for an idiom, not a single word:[Idiom for explaining something too thoroughly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408391/idiom-for-explaining-something-too-thoroughly)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Not unless you have another user-name. You do a lot of housework here. It's the individuals who don't seem to do any, but feel that they are still free to criticise. I found the [near?]-duplicates mentioned, but felt that a pedant could still argue against closure. [tidied; original comment 16 hours previous to this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [**circumlocution**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/circumlocution) - The use of many words where fewer would do, especially in a deliberate attempt to be vague or evasive.

Note that this does not necessarily mean repeating the same information, but certainly involves rambling on and beating about the bush. Also note that this is often used as a deliberate device to spin out information to fill time, or sometimes a poetic device to satisfy the metric requirements of a poem.

> The con man tried to use **circumlocution** to avoid explaining his real intentions to the wealthy couple

Depending upon circumstances, though, [**filibuster**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/filibuster) might also be appropriate - a delaying tactic; a long speech given in order to delay progress or the making of a decision.

> Strom Thurmond’s senate **filibuster** lasted over 24 hours

[oxforddictionaries.com]
[dictionary.com]

Comment: Already given in numerous answers.